# Solving the MIP at a node with same parameters as the root node

Tags: scip

In the branch-and-cut framework of SCIP, is it possible to solve a particular node of the tree with the same parameters (like presolving, restarts, etc.) as root node?

I want to get better bounds for particular nodes, and I think treating the problem at a node as root node can help. It will also lead to a different tree than the one I had gotten otherwise.

If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out-of-the-box.  You could implement a relaxator plugin that copies the MIP at the current node into a new SCIP instance (use SCIPcopy() with global = FALSE), solves it, and reports the result back to your main SCIP.

Comment: In addition to what Ambros writes, setting a node limit of 1 would be good.